# Replace item (mcpe)

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to replace an equipped leather cap with a glass block.
I tried `/replaceitem entity @s slot.armor.head glass`, but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

This is the syntax for `/replaceitem`:

```
/replaceitem <block|entity> <position or target> <slot type> <slot ID> <item name> [amount] [data] [components]
```

You forgot to define the `slot ID`, which in your case should be `0`:

```
/replaceitem entity @s slot.armor.head 0 glass
```

You can find more information about `/replaceitem` on [this site](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/replaceitem_command.php).

Comment: Thank you! This is a great help!